# Zabbix: Response time for web step indicates until HTTP code is received or everything is loaded?

Tags: zabbix

Response time for web steps (of a web scenario) indicates the time that it takes to load since the request is done until the HTTP code is received (200,302,404, etc) or until all the content is loaded? (images, css, javascripts, etc).
According to the docs: "Response time is counted from the beginning of the request until all information has been transferred." But "information" includes linked content??
Thanks!

Comment: From a quick test, I think that the external links are not included. Maybe you can set up a simple web page with a 1Mb jpg and test it. Then add an external link like a 1Mb js: if your time doubles or so, the external links are included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just the page content is evaluated: the HTML body, not the linked content. It's the same time it would take curl or wget to download the page, without recursive options.